# PHP class for PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal

I don't know where else to turn...

I have a client who insists on using PayPal as their credit card merchant. We will be taking cards directly on the site, so I suppose "Website Payments Pro" is the right avenue?

All of these different PayPal types, API's, accounts, etc. are all very confusing to me- I'm used to working with Stripe which is, in my opinion, the best, cleanest solution I have ever found.

Anyway, I have been looking everywhere for some sort of a PHP class to help me interact with the PayPal API as I have all but given up on figuring out how to interact with this thing from scratch. All of the classes I've found are several years old and no longer seem to function properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: I feel your pain, paypal have gone 'nuts with their new API.. I will try drag up the Class I used a while ago.

Comment: @Pogrindis - Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library this one looks up to date

Comment: Note i did use a work around of generating a payNow button based on inputs. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [PayPal PHP Class Library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make all of the PayPal Classic API calls very simple for you, including Payments Pro.  It has fully functional samples included with it, and then "templates" that are empty and ready for you to simply fill in your param values.  It handles the rest.

You can [see a sample of the output for DoDirectPayment here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/DoDirectPayment.php), which is the API that is used for Website Payments Pro 3.0 that you mentioned.  Note that it's working in the sandbox, and PayPal's sandbox is a little slow processing credit cards, so that sample might take a few moments to load, but the live servers don't do that.

You do need to make sure "Website Payments Pro" is what your client has enabled on their PayPal account if you're going to use DoDirectPayment, though.  PayPal has a new version where they dropped the "website" and they just call it "PayPal Payments Pro 2.0".  Yes, 2.0 is newer than 3.0.  There's a reason for that, and if you're curious you can [read about the history of PayPal Pro here](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/).

If the client has the newer PayPal Payments Pro 2.0 enabled then you'll need to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment.  The class library includes that as well, and you can [see a sample of its result here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/PayFlowTransaction.php).

Using the library you could get credit card processing up-and-running within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [Omnipay Package](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay); it's well maintained and it has [a lot of gateways](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#payment-gateways) for different payment services. I've started using it 8 months ago: it's simple and it works very well.